# HTML tag loop inside another tag

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom

I have a select and a list of `div` elements like this:

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
<button>submit</button>

<div id='list'>
    <div><h2>a</h2>0</div>
    <div><h2>b</h2>1</div>
    <div><h2>c</h2>2</div>
    <div><h2>d</h2>3</div>
    <div><h2>a</h2>0</div>
    <div><h2>b</h2>1</div>
    <div><h2>c</h2>2</div>
    <div><h2>d</h2>3</div>
</div>
```

I want to only show the `div` that has the `h2`'s text that matches the selected value.

I'm trying the following JavaScript loop:

```
<script>
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    var divItems = document.querySelectorAll('#table div');
    var h2Items = document.querySelectorAll('#table div h2');
    var button = document.querySelector('button');

    button.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var selectValue = select.value;

        for(i=0; i < divItems.length; i++){
            var h2Text = h2Items[i].innerHTML;
            if (h2Text == selectValue){
                divItems[i].display='block';
            } else {
                divItems[i].display='none';
            }
        }

    });
```

But it doesn't work.
The `console.log` show that the `h2`'s text and selected value are all correct,
but I don't know how to control the `div`'s style.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Judith, Welcome to Stack Overflow. FYI: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. `NodeList`'s support forEach in most browsers. The syntax is cleaner and as a result a bit easier to understand. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you are updating a style.

`divItems[i].display='block';` should be `divItems[i].style.display='block';`

AND

`divItems[i].display='none';` should be `divItems[i].style.display='none';`

Also, you are targeting `#table`, but you should be targeting `#list` since that is the id set on your main div.

Full JS:

```
<script>
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    var divItems = document.querySelectorAll('#list div');
    var h2Items = document.querySelectorAll('#list div h2');
    var button = document.querySelector('button');

    button.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var selectValue = select.value;

        for(i=0; i < divItems.length; i++){
            var h2Text = h2Items[i].innerHTML;
            if (h2Text == selectValue){
                divItems[i].style.display='block';
            } else {
                divItems[i].style.display='none';
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you very much. You saved my day.

Comment: So glad to hear it! If you wouldn't mind marking this answer as the correct one, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed couple of things which I will explain below but first here is the solution which works as expected:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select');
const divItems = document.querySelectorAll('#list div'); // this was #table 
const h2Items = document.querySelectorAll('#list div h2');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const selectValue = select.value;

    for(let i = 0; i < divItems.length; i++) {
        if (h2Items[i].innerHTML === selectValue){
            divItems[i].style = "display:block";
        } else {
            divItems[i].style = "display:none";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
<button>submit</button>

<div id="list">
    <div><h2>a</h2>0</div>
    <div><h2>b</h2>1</div>
    <div><h2>c</h2>2</div>
    <div><h2>d</h2>3</div>
    <div><h2>a</h2>0</div>
    <div><h2>b</h2>1</div>
    <div><h2>c</h2>2</div>
    <div><h2>d</h2>3</div>
</div>
```

**Suggestions:**

1. It is worth to check how `HTMLElement.style` works please find a link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).
2. Additionally learn the differences between `var`, `let` and `const`.
3. Last but not least differences between `==` and `===`.

I hope this helps!